# Demonstrate that the product of the permutations(regardless of order) of $S_4$ is not equal to $a$

Tags: permutations

$S_4$ is the set of all permutations of length 4

Let $a=\binom{1\,2\,3\,4}{3\,2\,1\,4}$

I found that $a$ is an odd permutation and I want to demonstrate that the product of the permutations is even but Im not sure if this is true and I have no idea how to demonstrate that.

Comment: Product of what permutations?

Comment: If you want to demonstrate the product of two odd permutations is even the use the definition. like in your case $a=(1,3)$ which has odd number of 2 cycles so is an odd permutation. In general any permutation $\tau$ can be split up into $2$ cycles, and if the number of $2$ cycles is odd, we say $\tau$ is odd, if number of $2$ cycles is even, then $\tau$ is called an even permutation

Comment: @S.C.: How about $({}^1_2\,{}^2_3\,{}^3_4\,{}^4_1)$? It consists of a single 4-cycle and _no_ 2-cycles, so according to your definition it should be even. But actually it's odd. What you want to say is that it is the product of an odd number of _transpositions_. It is true that a transposition and a 2-cycle is the same, but writing a permutation as a product of _cycles_ is not the same as writing it as a product of _transpositions_. "Split into cycles" usually implies that the cycles in question are disjoint.

Comment: @HenningMakholm $(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4) = (1\ 2) (1 \ 3 ) (1 \ 4 )$ which says its odd, since it has been split up into odd number of 2 cycles. and hence odd. Where is the error in my definition

Comment: @S.C.: The error is that what you show is _not the cycle decomposition_ of the permutation, and you should not speak about expressing a permutation as a product of _transpositions_ with the language for _splitting into cycles_. That just causes unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So how will u decompose $(1\  2 \ 3 \ 4 )$ as disjoint cycles? you can't right. It just is a single cycle isn't it?

Comment: @S.C.: It's just a single cycle, yes. But that doesn't mean it doesn't have a cycle decomposition. The cycle decomposition of $(1\,2\,3\,4)$ is $(1\,2\,3\,4)$ itself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah thats what i meant :). Thanks for taking time to clarify :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're saying is that if you take *all* the permutations in $S_4$ and multiply them together in whichever order, the result is never equal to your $a$.

Your basic plan is sound -- $a$ is indeed an odd permutation, and it will turn out that a product of all the permutations is even.

The product of all the permutations is even if and only if the total number of *odd* permutations in the product is *even*.

There are various ways of showing that. A quick and slick one is would be to know that exactly half of the elements of $S_n$ are odd (for $n\ge 2$), compute the size of $S_4$ and see that half of that number is even.

(Proof that exactly half of all permutations are odd: Fix some transposition -- say, your $a$ -- and then observe that if $\sigma$ is an even permutation, then $a\sigma$ is odd, and if $\tau$ is an even permutation, then $a\tau$ is an odd permutation such that $a(a\tau)=\tau$. So left multiplication by $a$ is a bijection between the even and the odd permutations, so there are equally many of them).